# Why lspci outputs the wrong id of my discrete graphics card?

Tags: nvidia, 12.04, vga

In an optimus enabled laptoto (Dell XPS 15 L502X) I have a discrete graphics card ( GT525M) and when running Nvidia-settings, one can confirm it:

[image: Nvidia Settings for GT525M]

Yet, 
The command:

```
 lspci -vnnn | grep VGA
```

outputs the following:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] [10de:0df5] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

The lspci command tells us the discrete card is GT540M and not GT525M. 
By no means I overclocked the card. Or does it mean the card comes undercocked.
I can't tell. A bug maybe?

While, before upgrading to 12.04, under 11.10 the same command did output GT525m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lspci is using a table of pci codes coming from http://pciids.sourceforge.net/v2.2/pci.ids
According to that list the device 10de:0df5 is NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M]

Maybe this is wrong and should be reported there, that eventually the next release of pciutils includes the corrected information? http://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/10de/0df5

(I do not have such device myself, so I cannot confirm)